# What is IPM.Note and what is its use?

Tags: exchange-server, mapi, exchange-server-2007, exchangewebservices

I have few questions about IPM.Note. It will be great if some one clear my doubts

1) What is IPM.Note? Is that a log file? Little detailed information so that i can understand

2) In my windows search when i type IPM.Note it showed me all my emails which is in my MS Outlook. But I can't see the word IPM.Note any where. how when i search IPM.Note, how i am getting all the email.msg files

3)Is there any chance IPM.Note will be in Exchange server 2007, or it will be in local machine?

4) How we will know from IPM.Note which all mail or in unread state.

5) How we will know from IPM.Note which all mail we have given reply

Thanks in advance

Comment: If I remember correctly, IPM.Note is the form for Notes in Outlook.

Answer (score 6):

"IPM.Note" is a message class (`MailItem.MessageClass` in the Outlook Object Model or `PR_MESSAGE_CLASS` in Extended MAPI) that tells Outlook what kind of item you have. "IPM" here stands for "InterPersonal Message"- messages like that are designed to be consumed by end users; but this is just a hint - it is perfectly valid for you to use a message class that does not start with "IPM" or use "IPM" even if you are dealing with a hidden message that an end user will never see.

On the low (MAPI) level, all items in Outlook are amorphous bags of properties. Message class tells Outlook how to treat a particular item - e.g. whether an Inbox message is a regular message, meeting invitation, or a report item (NDR) etc. Some other most frequently used message types are `IPM.Contact`, `IPM.Appointment`, `IPM.Task`. A comprehensive list of message classes used by Outlook can be found on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb176446%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

If you create a custom MAPI form, message class is how Outlook figures out which form to load when opening the item (e.g. "IPM.Note.MyCustomForm"). If the custom form is not found, Outlook will use its "parent" form (e.g.  "IPM.Note" if "IPM.Note.MyCustomForm" cannot be found).

You can take a look at the raw MAPI data in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) (I am its author - click the IMessage button). You can also see all locally installed MAPI forms and their message classes if you click the IMAPIFormMgr button.

Answer (score 4):

This MSDN page on [Item Types and Message Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb176446%28v=office.12%29.aspx) provides a nice catalog of IPM identifiers and they content type they represent. According to this, IPM.Note is the identifier for the Email Message type.